# An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. 'Provider=SQLOLEDB

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, oledb

I am creating an application which uses access file from shared network.The application works fine when the access file is placed local.But when I placed it in shared path and trying to connect.It is throwing an exception."**An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. 'Provider=SQLOLEDB**
Here is my code:

```
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\\MyFirstProject\\SampleDB2.accdb";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string command = "INSERT INTO emp_status(emp_id,hours,feeded_on,comments)";
            command += "VALUES(@emp_id,@hours,@feeded_on,@comments)";
```

Could anyone help me how to resolve this issue and Am I missing something?
I am using OLEB as a datasourse and Access 2013
Any Suggestions or explanations would definitely helps me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your error clearly specified that your application is not able to excess file as Shared folder required administrator rights to edit any file please have a look over it definitely it will solve your problem.

Comment: But I am to access the shared folder

Comment: Yeah I am getting your concern but your application needs the same privileges please run it as administrator.

Comment: Is there any mistake in my connection string

Comment: If it doesn't recognize the provider you are trying to use then it will always be a quick end to your program.  Simple kind of problem, easy to Google too, you either don't have the ACE provider installed on the machine or your program runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Yes,my application runs on a 64-bit machine.How do we know that ACE provider need to installed?

Comment: But why it is working fine when the file is in Local folders

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the leading double slash as well...

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\\\server\\MyFirstProject\\SampleDB2.accdb";
```

I haven't got anything to check this on here, but I'm fairly sure this is your answer. Also, watch out for reserved words, E.g. "hours" might be one in which case it should be [hours].

Also, you haven't specifically included adding the parameter values in your question. I assume you are doing it but if not then see my coding example here...

[VB 2010 error (INSERT INTO) syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259352/vb-2010-error-insert-into-syntax-error/41260907#41260907)