# VB 2010 error (INSERT INTO) syntax error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a program in VB.NET that will input data from textboxes into an Access database. Here is sample image:

[image]

This is the code I am using and it gives me an error:

```
m = TextBox1.Text
b = "'" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
x = "'" + TextBox3.Text + "'"
d = TextBox4.Text
n = "'" + TextBox5.Text + "'"
Dim s2 As String
s2 = "insert into users1 ( num , name1 , pass , add , phone ) " & " values ( " + m + " , " + n + " , " + b + " , " + x + " , " + d + " ) "
Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(s2, con)
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your SQL is failing is that "add" is a reserved word. i.e. you cannot use it without putting it in square brackets - [add]. As above you should parameterise your query, so one of these will work...

```
Using oleCmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into users1 (num,name1,pass,[add],phone) values (@num,@name1,@pass,@add,@phone)", con)
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@num", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Textbox1.Text
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@name1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox2.Text
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox3.Text
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Textbox4.Text
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Textbox5.Text
    oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

Using oleCmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into users1 (num,name1,pass,[add],phone) Values (?,?,?,?,?)", con)
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox1.Text)
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox2.Text)
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox3.Text)
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox4.Text)
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Textbox5.Text)
    oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Note, it will fail if the data types do not match what you are trying to insert, so if you try to insert text in num or phone it will fail. You will need to validate your input and preferably convert them rather than use the textbox Text.